# How to use my new domain from godaddy with my Apache2 server on Raspberry pi

Tags: apache2

I just purchased a domain from GoDaddy, let's call it example.com. I set it up on GoDaddy to where it forwards people to my home IP Address where my Raspberry Pi hosts my website using Apache2. How can I properly set it up so that it shows example.com in the address bar rather than my home IP address?

Here is my .conf file for my website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Change `ServerName www.example.com` to read whatever your domain is and restart Apache ..  Also you will need port 80 forwarded (On your homes router) to whatever internal IP address you have for it (Called `port forwarding` on most home routers).

Comment: Nope, this isn't it, still shows my IP address. I already have my domain put in for `ServerName www.example.com` and my website loads as intended, it's just the url bar still shows my IP address instead of my new domain.

Comment: Did you set your domain as an A record?  Not a CNAME ?  IE `A       *        123.123.123.123`

Comment: I created an A record on GoDaddy where: Name: @ Value: (My home IP) TTL: 1 Hour

Comment: Seems like on iPhone's I'm seeing my domain but on computers I am seeing my IP

Comment: Clear cache and flush DNS cache on your PC --  On windows command line DNS cache clear is `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Well that seemed to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visited the site via IP address prior to porting and setting a DNS record.  You may need to clear your browser and DNS cache.  This is how to flush Windows DNS via command line:

`ipconfig /flushdns`

Note that you MAY have to run `cmd` as admin.